# Getting values from two lists in a single lookup column

Tags: sharepoint-online

I have a situation where I need to get data in the `lookup field` from two lists which are having same column as `Country`. Means the `lookup field` should contain values of `country column` from both the lists.

Is it possible??

Comment: You can create two lookup column then.

Comment: But I need all the values in one column only..

Comment: Built in lookup field can create the relationship with only one other list. Are you looking for an OOB solution or custom script/app?

Comment: Anything will be fine..I jst need to get data from both list in one drop-down column

Comment: You can't have 1 `country` lookup that pulls data from two different lists; it's a 1-to-1 relationship. Maybe you could try adding two separate lookup columns, then hiding one of them (since it seems that it would be the same value populating it?). Then programmatically assign a value to the second drop down, based on the value the user inputs in the first drop down.